# Why does memset put a wrong value?

Tags: c, memset

I'm trying to fill zero regions in a matrix using memset() in this way:

```
unsigned short *ptr;
for(int i=0; i < nRows; ++i)
{
    ptr = DepthMat.ptr<unsigned short>(i); /* OCV matrix of uint16 values */
    for(int j=0; j<nCols; ++j)
    {
        uint n=0;
        if(ptr[j] == 0) /* zero region found */
        {
            d_val = ptr[j-1]; /* saves last non-zero value */
            while(ptr[j+n] == 0) 
            { /* looks for non zero */
                ++n;
            }
            d_val = (d_val < ptr[j+n] ? d_val : ptr[j+n]);
            memset( ptr+j, d_val, n*sizeof( ptr[0]) );
            j += n;
        }
    }
}
```

I look for sequences of zero, then I store the positions (`ptr+j-1` and `ptr+j+n`) and the values of the zero regions boundaries, and finally I use memset() to replace the zeros with d_val.
The problem is that when I check the values stored they don't match with d_val, for example, I put the value '222' but I get '57054'.
Any clue?

Comment: ptr is basically a pointer, so sizeof(ptr[0]) should be 4 bytes, instead of 2

Comment: `ptr[j-1];` addresses memory below &ptr[0] if j happens to be zero (which it is at the first teration of the loop) Also: `ptr = DepthMat.ptr<unsigned short>(i);` is a syntax error in C (are you using C++ ?) BTW2: what is `d_val` ?

Comment: @Ishmeet - no, since `ptr` points at an `unsigned short` the size of `ptr[0]` will be 2 - the size of an `unsigned short` (on most platforms). The size of `ptr` will be 4 (on most platforms).

Comment: @SteveFallows ok, since now ptr points at unsigned short, then sizeof ptr[0] is 2, but sizeof ptr is 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value argument to `memset()` is only a single byte, even though the type for the argument is `int`.

[The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) describes the function as:

> memset - fill memory with a constant byte

So, no more than the least-significant 8 bits of `d_val` will be written to memory. Since you're treating the memory as an array of `short`, you get "mangled" values that consist of the same byte repeated through the bytes of the `short`.

In ... short, don't do this; use a `for` loop to do a repeated write of actual `short`s.

Answer (score 2):

`memset` writes one char at a time, while you're accessing them as short. 57054 = 222*256+222

Comment: @Daniele C11 7.24.6.1  `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);` "The memset function copies the value of `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) into each of the first `n` characters of the object pointed to by `s`."